# How to use routes in seneca-web for rest api?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, seneca

I want to create rest API with seneca-web (express). I could not find any (full) documentation for a routes file used in it. I base one [these examples](https://github.com/senecajs/seneca-web/tree/master/docs/examples). Let's assume i have a resource called Task. I want to have these http methods:

- GET /tasks
- GET /tasks/:taskId
- POST /tasks

Here is routes.js:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    prefix: '/tasks',
    pin: 'role:api,path:*',
    map: {
      all: {
        GET: true,
        prefix: ''
      },
      ':taskId': {
        GET: true
      }

    }
  },
  {
    pin: 'role:api,path:*',
    map: {
      tasks: {
        POST: true
      }

    }
  }
]
```

and my seneca plugin for handling:

```
module.exports = function task (options) {
  this.add({role: 'api', path: 'all'}, function (msg, respond) {
    console.log(msg)
    this.act('role:task,cmd:all', respond)
    respond(null, [{name: 'First Task', description: 'Description of     the First Task'}])
  })
  this.add({role: 'api', path: '*'}, function (msg, respond) {
    console.log(msg)
    this.act('role:task,cmd:single', {taskId: msg.args.params.taskId}, respond)
  })
}
```

- I am not sure how to separate POST and GET actions here.
- I found also problematic the fact that keys in map object of routes are taken as a part  of a path, eg. GET /tasks/all instead of GET /tasks.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: @aman_novice yeah, I used aliases there, but I am not a fan of integration of Seneca with express.js :)

Comment: I hope you were using Seneca to develop an app using the micro-services architecture. can you suggest the alternate route you took?

Comment: @aman_novice yes, but the routing was for external API of the system (REST API for some browser client). The problem was to use common naming for resources paths. what suggestion do you expect? because I don't know if I solved your problem?

Answer (score -1):

here is example of seneca-web with routes

=========index.js=======

```
const seneca = require('seneca')()
const express = require('express')()
const web = require('seneca-web')
const cors = require('cors')

var Routes = [{
  prefix: '/products',
  pin: 'area:product,action:*',
  map: {list: {GET: true}}
}]
express.use(cors())
var config = {
  routes: Routes,
  adapter: require('seneca-web-adapter-express'),
  context: express,
  options: {parseBody: true}
}
seneca.client()
.use(web, config)
.ready(() => {
  var server = seneca.export('web/context')()
  server.listen('8082', () => {
    console.log('server started on: 8082')
  })
})
seneca.add({area: 'product', action: 'list'}, function (args, done) {
  try {
    done(null, {response: 'Product List'})
  } catch (err) {
    done(err, null)
  }
})
```

start app using command :
node index.js

open link in your browser 
http://localhost:8082/products/list

Comment: It's not what was asked in the question. I know how to configure seneca basically.